# Styled-theming issue with typings (Typescript)

Tags: typescript-typings, styled-components

I use `styled-components` in conjunction with `styled-theming` in my react-native project pre-configured with TypeScript.

I have a problem with exported `theme` function from the `styled-theming` lib. It doesn't recognize passed props to the function. Let me show what I mean...

Firstly, this is a slice of my `package.json` file

```
"styled-components": "^5.0.1",
"styled-theming": "^2.2.0"

"@types/styled-components": "^4.4.3",
"@types/styled-theming": "^2.2.2",

"typescript": "^3.7.5"
```

Secondly, this is my `component.styles.ts` file

[image]

As you can see on the image below typings of the `props` of the `styled-components` are okay.

[image]

But they are not used inside `theme` function

[image]

Is there any idea of how to resolve the issue? I expect to have proper typings inside my `theme` function.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your `theme` function signature looks like, but you might be running into [this caveat](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#caveat-with-function-components) where you need to explicitly set the theme as a argument to the interface. You might try importing the theme object from `styled-components` and creating a new function -

```
import {DefaultTheme} from 'styled-components'

interface ThemeProps {
   theme: DefaultTheme
}

function setTextColor(props: ThemeProps){
   return theme('mode', {...implementation_here...})
}

export const TextStyled = styled.Text`
  color: ${props => setTextColor(props)}
`
```